# Is it ok to add helper methods to redux store?

Tags: redux

I'm making an SVG chart and I have a bunch of helper methods for converting between coordinates and dates. Currently I need to apply scaling everywhere and it's annoying, so I was considering adding the helper methods to the redux store, where the store has access to scaling and can automatically apply it in the methods.

Is this ideal?

I'm also considering creating a function that takes scale, and returns all of the helper methods with the scale curried in. If I do it this way, then I need to reinstantiate this curried function in every file I use it, passing scale each time.

Using redux store I'd only have to do it once.

EDIT: More detail

Restriction: "store" is inaccessible, outside of perhaps middleware.

convert

```
getDateFromX(x) / scale
```

to just

```
getDateFromX(x)
```

Where scale is built into the function. Like, getDateFromX is always divided by scale, so it should be in the function, but the scale is in the redux store.

I was originally asking if I could have my application reducer return a function in it's returned object "getDateFromX" that could be grabbed through mapStateToProps in connect. I understand it's frowned upon, or I wouldn't have asked the original question, I would have simply implemented this.

Also, there are about 7 more functions that do similar conversions. Converting between hours, days, date, and x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You *could* technically do that, I guess, but it's definitely not a good use of Redux.  (I'm actually having trouble envisioning how "methods attached to the store" would actually fit into things.)

The more idiomatic approach would be to use selector functions.  For example:

```
import {createSelector} from "reselect";

const selectScale = state => state.scale;

const selectSomeValue = state => state.someValue;

const selectScaledValue = createSelector(
    selectScale, selectSomeValue,
    (scale, somevalue) => scale * someValue
);
```

If you consistently use `selectScaledValue()` in your `mapStateToProps` functions, then it would give you the scaled value every time *either* the scale or the original value changes.

Comment: The helpers don't have access to the redux state, because the store isn't exposed outside of connect and saga middleware.

So I'll have to take what you wrote and put it in a function, and curry in the scale, in each component then.

A lot of duplication, but I suppose there is no better way.

Comment: Oh I see, that's what reselect is for. Another middleware for exposing the redux state.

hmmm... I still prefer a curried function, because it's hard to tell that a random function happens to have redux state in it.

Thanks though!

Comment: Reselect isn't a "middleware". It's a generic lib for creating memoized functions, that just happens to work very well with Redux. You can use these functions anywhere, but they're most commonly used in `mapState` functions and thunks/sagas, to help retrieve data that's nested in your Redux state tree. You may want to read some of the articles on selectors I have listed at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md#selectors-and-normalization .

Comment: So I still need to provide it access to my store.

Then reselect is useless, because the store only belongs in react-redux, and redux-saga, and the index file. Otherwise you expose it globally.

Comment: Ah... no, not exactly.  Again, Reselect functions are just functions.  You would normally _use_ them in places where the store state is accessible or has been provided, but they're not _tied_ to the store in any way.  I guess I'm having trouble understanding your use case. Can you update your question to provide some sample pseudocode and a more detailed description for what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: Good call. I shall do that.

Answer (score 2):

As our app grows we have been running into similar issues. We try to keep our state as small as possible and then calculate additional information on demand. We've found this to be fairly robust but as the app grows we have to import these state helper functions throughout the app and it's not so user friendly. I've been toying with the idea of taking all the state helpers and attaching them to the state objects in a middleware piece so that components have easy access to them but they aren't actually being stored in our Redux store. I think you could combine markerikson's point but instead of duplicating these functions across your codebase pass them around with the state.

So instead of doing this all over your app

```
import { getDateFromX } from 'helpers'

...

getDateFromX(state)
```

You do this:

```
[ REDUX ] ---> [ CONNECT ] ---> [ UI ]
           ^
           |
   Attach helpers here
```

And then as your state is passed around you can do `state.helpers.getDateFromX`

This isn't fully fleshed out but I've also been trying to come up with an elegant solution to this issue that doesn't violate best practices of Redux.